# A List inside a list in django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

How do you render a list of user who have a list of their own objects related with foreign-key in Models. When I render in html it brings all list of all users in all users,

**EDIT**

Sorry for late reply, I rarely get time to get to my computer,

I have three models, Profile, Resume and Skills with the two related to Profile through foreign key...

VIEWS.PY

```
class ResumeList(ListView):
    model = User_Profile
    context_object_name = 'profile'
    template_name = 'resume/list.html'
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['resume'] = Resume.objects.all()
        context['skill_list'] = Skill.objects.all()
        return context
```

LIST.HTML

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    {% for obj in profile %}
        {{ obj.first_name }}
        {{ obj.last_name }}

        {% for obj in resume %}
            {{ obj.resume }}
        {% endfor %}

        {% for obj in skill_list %}
            {{ obj.name }}
        {% endfor %}

    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

The Resume and Skill model loops are inside the profile loop but it displays all skills for all profiles...

When I change the get_context_data() to filter it brings error...
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Perhaps you better share that template then, right now it is rather unclear what is happening.

Comment: and the view and models.